# Logstash 5 is not outputting filebeat input and Kafka input

Tags: logstash, apache-kafka

Below is configuration on Logstash 5 server

```
input {
kafka {
topics => ["logstash_logs"]
bootstrap_servers => "zk_server:2181"
codec => plain {
format => "%{message}"
}
}
}

input {
beats {
port => 5044
ssl => true
ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
}
}

output{
stdout{}
}
```

filebeat is configured on same machine as that of Logstash server. It is configured correctly as well.

Still I cannot see data in /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout .

logstash is started with -log.level=debug still I cannot see any thing in log /var/log/logstash/logstash.log

Please help me to debug setup

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrap_servers` refers to the Kafka broker itself, not the Zookeeper instance. Starting with Kafka 0.9, the consumer doesn't directly deal with Zookeeper anymore (unless it really wants to).

The real problem here is that Logstash doesn't provide enough information for a user to deduce why this isn't working. Also the documentation doesn't make it clear that this is Kafka and not Zookeeper. They do provide a hint in the default port number of `:9092`, however.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-bootstrap_servers

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number from `2181` to `9092`, had the same problem. 
Check the logs, do a tail on the logstash log `tail -f -10 /var/log/logstash/logstash.log` you should see `ipaddress:2181` connection refused.